# read from an array inside printf arg. printf("%widthArr[0]u, %widthArr[1]u ", var1, var2)

Tags: c, arrays, printing, formatting, printf

I am trying to use width array for printing variables in specific widths.  I want to do something like

```
int widthArr[] = {5, 4};
uint32_t var1 = 123; 
uint32_t var2 = 4567;
printf("%widthArr[0]u, %widthArr[1]u ", var1, var2);
```

but using the actual values from `widthArr` for the widths.  Can that be done?

Comment: What is your program inteded to do? Print out the values at `widthArr[0]` and `widthArr[1]`?

Comment: Hi @pytheos, the program needs to print the variables in different widthes.
like printf("%5u, %4u ", var1, var2);

Comment: Note: Use `PRIu32` rather than `"%u"` . `"%u"`is for `unsigned`, not necessarily `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the width, you can use a `*` modifier to read the field width from the arguments, like this:

```
printf("%*u, %*u ", widthArr[0], var1, widthArr[1], var2);
// prints  "  123, 4567 "
```

From [the C++ reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> In the case when `*` is used, the width is specified by an additional
>   argument of type `int`.

Note that asterisks may also be used to dynamically set the precision.